# Pytorch is not working with trained model+pretrained model (Intel Open Vino)

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, openvino

```
def PeopleBox(PeopleNet,frame):
frameHeight=frame.shape[0]
frameWidth=frame.shape[1]
blob=cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (672,384), swapRB=False, crop=True)
PeopleNet.setInput(blob)
detection=PeopleNet.forward()
bboxs=[]
for i in range(detection.shape[2]):
    confidence=detection[0,0,i,2]
    if confidence>0.7:
        x1=int(detection[0,0,i,3]*frameWidth)
        y1=int(detection[0,0,i,4]*frameHeight)
        x2=int(detection[0,0,i,5]*frameWidth)
        y2=int(detection[0,0,i,6]*frameHeight)
        bboxs.append([x1,y1,x2,y2])
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0), 8)
return frame, bboxs



PeopleBin = (r"C:\Users\directory\T1\pedestrian-detection-adas-0002.bin")
PeopleXml = (r"C:\Users\directory\T1\pedestrian-detection-adas-0002.xml")
HelmetBin = (r"C:\Users\dc\StructVGGV1_output\VGG16_V1_40epohc_LR0_00008_batch4_A96_V77.bin")
HelmetXml = (r"C:\Users\dc\StructVGGV1_output\VGG16_V1_40epohc_LR0_00008_batch4_A96_V77.xml")
PeopleNet=cv2.dnn.readNet(PeopleXml, PeopleBin)
HelmetNet=cv2.dnn.readNet(HelmetXml,HelmetBin)
List = ['NoPersonHoldingHelmet', 'PersonHoldingHelmet']
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
ret,frame=video.read()
framee,bboxs=PeopleBox(PeopleNet,frame)
for bbox in bboxs:
    ########check
    blob=cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(framee, 1.0, (224,224), swapRB=False, crop = True) 
    HelmetNet.setInput(blob)
    ###########
    HelmetPred=HelmetNet.forward()
    Helmet=List[HelmetPred[0].argmax()]
    #label="{},{}".format(Helmet,HelmetPred)
    label="{}".format(Helmet)
    if label=="NoPersonHoldingHelmet":
        cv2.rectangle(framee, (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[2],bbox[3]), (255,0,255), 8)
    if label == "PersonHoldingHelmet":
        cv2.rectangle(framee, (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[2],bbox[3]), (255,255,0), 8)
        
    cv2.putText(framee, label, (bbox[0]-70, bbox[1]-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 2,cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("Helmet_Vs_NoHelmet",framee)
cv2.imshow("Helmet_Vs_NoHelmet",framee)
k=cv2.waitKey(1)
if k==ord('q'):
    break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I trained my model with Pytorch using google colab. After I trained my model, I converted my model into IR using Intel Open Vino (https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.3/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_PyTorch.html)
After that, I combined pretrained pedestrian model (https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/omz_models_model_pedestrian_detection_adas_0002.html) and my model together (object detection + recognition like license plate recognition/detection).
However, the combined model is not working correctly... I checked my model's accuracy and it was near 96 percent. Therefore, I am not sure what is causing the issue. I have been hard stuck in this for so long time.

I uploaded my colab below I used to train my model
[enter link description here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HEF5oabA7KRGWmZk0bi_35MEu-LhQ658?usp=drive_link)

Comment: I had requested access for the model

Comment: Plus, could you explain further what is your expected output and what did you get instead (what made you say the model is not working correctly, eg:wrong detection) ?

Comment: So I tested my model and it has an accuracy of 94 percent. However, whenever I load the model in to dnn open cv, it looks like it detects randomly. In other words, I feel like the accuracy of A is >>> B in List [A, B].  Sorry, It's hard to find a better way to explain this issue.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post. By posting on Stack Overflow, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 licence](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts will result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested and compared your model with OpenVINO pretrained model pedestrian-detection-adas-0002 since you mentioned that this is the reference to your DL model development.

I inferred both model with Object Detection Python Demo ( I get this from [OMZ repo](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/object_detection_demo/python))

My finding is that your model does not have the correct wrapper as the OV model.The pedestrian-detection-adas-0002 uses network based on SSD framework with tuned MobileNet v1 as a feature extractor.

Perhaps this is the part that you need to cater to your custom model.

[image: customer model vs pedestrian-detection-adas-0002]

Comment: Can you explain last part in detail? "My finding is that your model does not have the correct wrapper as the OV model.The pedestrian-detection-adas-0002 uses network based on SSD framework with tuned MobileNet v1 as a feature extractor." I am not understanding here clearly... So that means I have to train my model with pretrained mobilenetV1 CNN in order to work with pedestrian-detection-adas-0002?

I thought what you said only apply to the openvino demo.py not for dnn method like what I did..i..

Comment: Please help to refer to the photo that I attached and see the error that had been prompted when I use your model with OpenVINO Object Detection Demo instead of the result that I get when running the  pedestrian-detection-adas-0002 model.

Comment: So, If you are trying to replicate what  pedestrian-detection-adas-0002 model does, you'll need to have similar architecture and framework to make yours able to implement the same abilities. I believe you already familiar with the pretrained model details since you shared [this documentation](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.3/omz_models_model_pedestrian_detection_adas_0002.html) in your question. The best way is to test inferring with official OpenVINO demo since it's not likely to have issues. Plus, the prompted error would give hints on what to fix.

Comment: Another thing to be clear is, coding algorithm in developing model (eg:PyTorch, etc) and coding algorithm for inferring (eg:OpenVINO Object Detection Demo) are two different codes & stage. (PyTorch -> model conversion to IR -> use model in OpenVINO IR format with OpenVINO IE demo)